how do I reimage a Surface Go Tablet while retaining it's original windows key?
I work for a small company where I'm a software developer and we distribute our software on Surface Go tablets. I'm the only 'IT' guy here and the surface Go tablets that we buy already have a licensed Windows Pro installed and all I do is configure it manually and then install my own software on it and give it to our customers...
Very amateuristic, I know. It's just that I don't have any experience with this...
I can probably figure out how to take an image one way or the other but I don't want to overwrite the existing windows license.
How can I be sure to retain the original Windows license if I re-image a Surface Tablet with Windows-(key) already installed on it when purchased? Can I extract the key somehow?
Is there any (simple) software or tool that I can use or purchase that helps me with this?

The Windows key is embed in the ACPI table.  Saving the Windows key is unnecessary as it will automatically be detected during the Windows installation.  Software recommendations are out of scope here at Super User. Windows 10 and Windows 11 will automatically activate.

As Ramhound says the key should be stored in the system firmware. If you are going the drive imaging route then copying the image from one machine to another should invalidate the key activation that was present on the old machine, which will have been locked to varous system components, forcing it to revalidate with the key stored in the ACPI table. In theory you should just end up with an activated system. Alternatively Microsoft provide standard system images for their Surface line which you can install and then install your software on top of.

From my experience windows 10 and 11 should automatically activate
Anyway, correct me if I am wrong, by opening a CMD as administrator
and launching the command:
wmic path softwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey
you can obtain the involved product key- i.e.
the string of alphanumeric chars replaced by stars in this example:
C:\Windows\System32> wmic path softwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey
OA3xOriginalProductKey
*****-*****-*****-*****-*****
C:\Windows\System32>

BTW:
given that this key is probably linked to that specific device, I am not sure that it can be useful besides for archival purposes
